# Change the file path based on a previous sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a .pdf and set the print area for my sheet named "TELECOM" from the cell "A1" to the last row of my data sheet. Depending on the cell value on sheet "TELECOM", I want the file name to be named accordingly. The initial directory in on sheet "Header Info", cell D11. I then grab this initial directory (according to given information on the other cells in column D) and then take it to a more specific directory afterwards.

I have tried using the commands such as ExportAsFixedFormat and Type:=xlTypePDF but had very little success.

```
Sub MakeaPDF()
Dim LstRw As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Set wSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TELECOM")
With Sheets("TELECOM")
Set wSheet = Sheets("TELECOM")
    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("A1:F" & LstRw)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").PageSetup.PrintArea = Rng.Address
        If .Range("A1").Value = "30% Design Review" Then
        Sheets("Header Info").ExportAsFixedFormat , Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D11") & "\Design\_Common\Transmittals\30% DESIGN REVIEW\COMM\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D14") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D15") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D18") & "_" & "COMM" & "_" & "30%_Design_Review_Xmittal.pdf"
        ElseIf .Range("A1").Value = "Final Design Review" Then
        Sheets("Header Info").ExportAsFixedFormat , Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D11") & "\Design\_Common\Transmittals\FINAL DESIGN REVIEW\COMM\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D14") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D15") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D18") & "_" & "COMM" & "_" & "Final_Design_Review_Xmittal.pdf"
        ElseIf .Range("A1").Value = "Construction Submittal" Then
        Sheets("Header Info").ExportAsFixedFormat , Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D11") & "\Design\_Common\Transmittals\FINAL ISSUE\COMM\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D14") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D15") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D18") & "_" & "COMM" & "_" & "Final_Issue_Xmittal.pdf"
        End If
End With
End Sub
```

I would like to create a .pdf in the corresponding folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub MakePDF()

    Dim Répertoire As String
    Dim Fichier As String

    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Sheet1 = Sheets("TELECOM")
    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("A1:F" & LstRw)


    'Put your repertory
    Répertoire = ""


    If Worksheets("Header info").Range("A1").Value = "30% Design Review" Then

        Fichier = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D11") & "\Design\_Common\Transmittals\30% DESIGN REVIEW\COMM\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D14") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D15") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D18") & "_" & "COMM" & "_" & "30%_Design_Review_Xmittal.pdf"
    Else
        If Worksheets("Header info").Range("A1").Value = "Final Design Review" Then
            Fichier = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D11") & "\Design\_Common\Transmittals\FINAL DESIGN REVIEW\COMM\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D14") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D15") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D18") & "_" & "COMM" & "_" & "Final_Design_Review_Xmittal.pdf"
        Else
            If Worksheets("Header info").Range("A1").Value = "Construction Submittal" Then
                Fichier = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D11") & "\Design\_Common\Transmittals\FINAL ISSUE\COMM\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D14") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D15") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Header Info").Range("D18") & "_" & "COMM" & "_" & "Final_Issue_Xmittal.pdf"
            End If
        End If
    End If


    Sheet1.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=Répertoire & Fichier, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is still saving to my documents folder. Is there a work around?

Comment: Thank you for working to resolve this. Could you add some explanation about what you changed so other users can learn from your solution? (thx)

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to check for is that the folder (which you're exporting to) already exists and that the filename is valid. My checks might cover some common cases, but they aren't exhaustive.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeaPDF()

    Dim telecomSheet As Worksheet
    Set telecomSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TELECOM") ' Change sheet's codename and use that instead maybe?

    Dim headerInfoSheet As Worksheet
    Set headerInfoSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Header Info")

    Dim lastRowOnTelecomSheet As Long
    lastRowOnTelecomSheet = telecomSheet.Cells(telecomSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Could you export the range/selection of cells -- rather than assiging the print area?
    headerInfoSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = telecomSheet.Range("A1:F" & lastRowOnTelecomSheet).Address

    Dim folderPathStartsWith As String
    folderPathStartsWith = headerInfoSheet.Range("D11") & "\Design\_Common\Transmittals\"

    Dim folderPathEndsWith As String
    Dim filenameEndsWith As String

    Select Case LCase$(headerInfoSheet.Range("A1"))
        Case "30% design review"
            folderPathEndsWith = "30% DESIGN REVIEW\COMM\"
            filenameEndsWith = "30%_Design_Review_Xmittal.pdf"
        Case "final design review"
            folderPathEndsWith = "FINAL DESIGN REVIEW\COMM\"
            filenameEndsWith = "Final_Design_Review_Xmittal.pdf"
        Case "construction submittal"
            folderPathEndsWith = "FINAL ISSUE\COMM\"
            filenameEndsWith = "Final_Issue_Xmittal.pdf"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Could not determine folder and filename of export. Code will stop running now to prevent unpredictable behaviour."
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = folderPathStartsWith & folderPathEndsWith

    If Len(Dir$(folderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "'" & folderPath & "' is not a valid directory. Code will stop running now."
        Exit Sub ' Or you could create the directory here, if it doesn't exist, with MkDir
    End If

    With headerInfoSheet
        Dim pdfFilename As String
        pdfFilename = .Range("D14") & "_" & .Range("D15") & "_" & .Range("D18") & "_" & "COMM" & "_" & filenameEndsWith
    End With

    ' You may need to try to check if the filename is valid (if it's not, you may get an error when you go to export it)
    If StringContainsReservedCharacters(pdfFilename) Or Len(pdfFilename) > 260 Then
        ' Or you could replace any illegal characters with a legal character
        MsgBox "'" & pdfFilename & "' doesn't appear to be a valid filename. Code will stop running now."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    headerInfoSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=folderPath & pdfFilename
End Sub

Private Function StringContainsReservedCharacters(ByVal stringToCheck As String) As Boolean
    Const RESERVED_CHARACTERS As String = "<>:""/\|?*" 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file
    Dim characterIndex As Long
    For characterIndex = 1 To Len(RESERVED_CHARACTERS)
        If InStr(1, stringToCheck, Mid$(RESERVED_CHARACTERS, characterIndex, 1), vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            StringContainsReservedCharacters = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next characterIndex
End Function
```

If you run into a `MsgBox`, hopefully you'll know why it's not working.